# Validating decimal precision

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Hi I am trying to a calculation and I am using the fluent validation pack to ensure that my rules are adhered to

The validation is firing and going into the rules ok but stil not working 100%

```
SageOrderMixB sageOrder = new  SageOrderMixB();
var validator = new MixValidator();
var results = validator.Validate(sageOrder);


public class MixValidator : AbstractValidator<SageOrderMixB>
{
    public MixValidator()
    {            
        RuleFor(x => x.WeightInTons).LessThanOrEqualTo(28).ScalePrecision(2, 2).WithMessage("Weight cannot be greater than 28 and must be a precison of 2"); ;

    }
}
```

However, If I enter the weight as 29 it is still bypassing and failing my units tests

Here you will see me traping before i add to my model

```
 if (results.IsValid == false)
 {
    sberror.Clear();
    foreach (var item in results.Errors)
    {
      sberror.Append(item.ErrorMessage);
    }
 MessageBox.Show("Please correct the following " + sberror.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
            sageOrdersList.Add(sageOrder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it was the position of where I was doing this ensure you have it after where you set you values

> var results = validator.Validate(sageOrder);

Answer (score 5):

Here:

`.ScalePrecision(2,2)`

The first `2` is the number of decimal places. The second `2` is number of numeric positions.

`0.45 <-- this is valid`
`1.45 <-- this is invalid`

e.g.

`.ScalePosition(2,4)`

`27.24 <-- this is valid`

Source: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#scaleprecision-validator

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use Regular Expression for that.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{2,2})$")]
```